# Plotting specific points on a graph

Tags: python, plot, graphing, labeling

I need some help with plotting data on graphs. So I would like to plot this data from a machine called a mass spectrometer. The data consists of intensity (plotted on y axis) and Mass/charge ration (m/z) (plotted on the x axis). In this task, I have to plot the data (which I have successfully done) and label all the peaks on the data that have an intensity of half of the maximum (which I have failed to complete successfully). This is what I have done so far but I continually get `ValueErrors`.  Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
plt.clf()
xs = np.arange(0,10,1)
ys = np.random.normal(loc=3, scale=0.4, size=10)

plt.plot(xs,ys)
Max_y= ys.max()
HalfMax_y=Max_y/2
if ys > HalfMax_y:

    for x,y in zip(xs, ys):

        label = "{:.3f}".format(y)

        plt.annotate(label,
                     (x,y),
                     textcoords="offset points",
                     xytext=(0,10), 
                     ha='center',
                     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='green'))
    plt.show()
```

Here is the error message for context:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-284991f08763> in <module>
      6 Max_y= ys.max()
      7 HalfMax_y=Max_y/2
----> 8 if ys > HalfMax_y:
      9 
     10     for x,y in zip(xs, ys):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly. We don't know what your input is (a sample data set of some points recflecting the data structure of your real input is enough)  and what exactly the error message is.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Hi @furas and Mr. T, I have made the necessary changes to the code! Let me know if you have enough info to help me out!

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. You have array `HalfMax_y` and when you compare `ys > HalfMax_y` then it creates array `[True, True, False, ...]` and  `if` doesn't know if it should treat it as `True` or `False`. So it ask to use `if (ys > HalfMax_y).any():` or `if (ys > HalfMax_y).all():`. But maybe you expect something different - so you could use `print()` to see if variables have values which you expect.

Comment: I thin you should use do it inside `for`-loop with `if y > HalfMax_y:`

Answer (score 0):

Problem makes

```
ys > HalfMax_y
```

because it gives list

```
[ True  True  False ...]
```

so you have

```
if [ True  True  False ...]:
```

and it doesn't know if it should treat it as `True` or `False` - so it ask to use

```
if (ys > HalfMax_y).all():
```

or

```
if (ys > HalfMax_y).any():
```

---

But I think this need different code - you should check `HalfMax_y` inside `for`-loop

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

xs = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
ys = np.random.normal(loc=3, scale=0.4, size=10)

plt.plot(xs,ys)

max_y = ys.max()

half_max_y = max_y / 2

#print( ys > half_max_y )  # [ True  True  False ...]

for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    
    if y > half_max_y:

        label = "{:.3f}".format(y)

        plt.annotate(label,
                     (x,y),
                     textcoords="offset points",
                     xytext=(0,10), 
                     ha='center',
                     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='green'))

plt.show()
```